# Recurrence relation solving

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, recurrence-relations

Dear friends I want to learn how to solve the recurrence relation
$f_{n,k}(x)=xf_{n-1,k}(x)-f_{n-2,k}(x)+2x^k (x-2)$, where $n$ and $k$ are positive integers and $n-k\ge5$.

Comment: Some initial conditions are required. Do you know what $f_{0,k}(x)$ and $f_{1,k}(x)$ are?

Comment: If you fix $k$ and $x$, this is a linear recurrence using the remaining variable $n$.  Do you know methods for that?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The initial conditions are $f_{k+5,k}(x)$ and $f_{k+6,k}(x)$. These are two polynomials known to me. Let us call them $A(k,x)$ and $B(k,x)$. Then how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: Respected GEdgar, I am not aware of solving linear recurrence relations. Kindly help